# C# Constructor Performance: Default Values vs Manual Declaration

Tags: c#, performance

I encounterd some code where a constructor of a relative simple class was used and its fields where set explicitely to default values. I wondered if i could improve performance by deleting these explicit use of default values, since they are set automatically?

I have some class like this:

```
class RatherSimpleClass
{
    public int myNumber;
    public String myName;
    public bool myBool;
}
```

And i wonder if in the following example creating s2 is more performant than s1? I would expect using the second declaration would result in a slightly better performance, but i am not sure, since i do not know how to measure that properly. In addition i wonder, what the best practice would be?

```
RatherSimpleClass s1 = new RatherSimpleClass
{
    myNumber = 0,
    myName = null,
    myBool = false,

};
RatherSimpleClass s2 = new RatherSimpleClass { };
```

---

Edit after seeing the answer of JonasH: I tried the following measurement:

```
int iterations = 1_000_000_000;
while (true)
{
    s.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        RatherSimpleClass rsc = new()
        {
            myNumber = 0,
            myName = null,
            myBool = false
        };
    }
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"explicit:\t{s.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    s.Reset();
    s.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
    {
        RatherSimpleClass rsc = new();
    }
    s.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine($"autodefault:\t{s.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    s.Reset();
}
```

which led to following output:

```
explicit:       6106
autodefault:    5415
explicit:       5814
autodefault:    5481
explicit:       5702
autodefault:    5507
explicit:       5761
autodefault:    5517
...
```

So I guess the performance of autodefault values is about 10% faster.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the JIT optimizer will produce the same code (not 100% sure, but it seems like an easy thing to optimize). How many of these are you planning on constructing? I generally don't concern myself with a handful of machine instructions. I noticed your `{}`. There is a difference in code gen between a constructor that takes initial values for members as parameters, setting the values in the body and a constructor that includes property setters within `{}`. One is construct and initialize, the other is construct followed by initialize.

Comment: @Flydog57 It is intended on server side. So i am planning for about 1000 per day.
I too had a suspicion, that at the end the produced code in these two version won't even differ.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Best practice would be:

1. Change your fields to properties
2. If you can, make the properties read only, i.e. `{get; init;}`
3. If any properties are required, add the `required` keyword (C#11) or add a constructor to force them to be set.
4. The object itself should ensure it is initialized with appropriate defaults. If you just want a default object you should just do `new RatherSimpleClass()`.

But this has nothing to do with performance. Only code style and making things easier to read and maintain.

The first thing you should do whenever you are concerned about performance is to **measure**. The easiest way is to use a stopwatch, the best way is Benchmark.Net. A profiler is also handy to have to tell you what parts are slow. I would expect there to be no to negligible difference, but please do your own measuring. What I am certain about is that you will not notice any difference if you are only constructing a few thousand objects a day. I'm also fairly certain that you have much significant performance problems than this, and that your time is better spent doing some profiling to find potential bottlenecks.